# Next.js 13 + AWS CDK v2, amplify. 500 Internal Server Error in dynamic routing SSR

Tags: cors, aws-amplify, server-side-rendering, aws-cdk, next.js13

Made a small next.js13 project with amplify and CDKv2. When I go to url -> item/[id] it gives me 500 internal Server error. This issue is only after I deploy to production. Everything works in local when i test it with npm run dev.

Couldnt find any solution to this problem anywhere.

Note -> there are no API written. just getting items.tsx file from inside app directory.it exports one variable called items which is a list of json items.

Tried few things.

- Did some console.log in the item/[id] page.tsx. None of them gets logged.
- tried clean installing npm packages, doesnt work.
- checked console of web. says internal server error 500 and "A client-side exception has occured"
- checked the build stage of Amplify (Frontend), the only useful thing i saw there, is my page was treated as server.

Route (app)                                Size     First Load JS

├ λ /(.)item/[id]                       0 B                0 B

└ λ /item/[id]                          777 B            99 kB

[INFO]: λ  (Server)  server-side renders at runtime (uses getInitialProps or getServerSideProps)

- Checked Access Logs

[Access Logs Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLGKq.png)
[Access Logs Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fV7B7.png)
Here I see it says OriginError in x-edge-detailed-result-type.

Spent alot of time looking to fix this OriginError, tried modifying next.config.js in different ways with all sorts of headers, even with "*".

Answer (score 2):

I enabled Amplify Hosting Compute Logs and saw this in CloudWatch logs:

> Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './server.edge'
> is not defined by "exports" in
> /var/task/node_modules/react-dom/package.json at new NodeError
> (node:internal/errors:387:5) at throwExportsNotFound
> (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:365:9) at packageExportsResolve
> (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:649:3) at resolveExports
> (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:556:36) at Function.Module._findPath
> (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:596:31)  .....(some more few lines)
> ... code: 'ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED' }

This seems to be a known issue. [Link](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/49169)
There is a simple amplify fix for this:

1. Set environment variable `__NEXT_PRIVATE_PREBUNDLED_REACT=next`
2. Add server runtime access to build settings of your frontend:

build:

```
commands:
  - env | grep -e __NEXT_PRIVATE_PREBUNDLED_REACT >> .env.production
  - npm run build
```

This should solve the issue.